# nodeJS - csv parse with createReadStream, how can every chunk be converted to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-csv-parse

I was using the csv-parse package with the createReadStream method.

```
fs.createReadStream('rando.csv')
    .pipe(parse({
        comment: '#', 
        columns: true, 
    }))
    .on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        
    })
```

The above code logs objects, my question is, is it reading the csv file row by row? or else what it prints wouldn't be a complete object right? Is a chunk equal to one line?

Comment: So what did you see in the log? Does in contain one line? You can answer your own question by looking at your log.

Comment: @RickyMo it seems to be that way for the csv file, but when I create a text file and read it, it doesn't log every line but rather the entire thing as a whole.

Comment: When using stream, I would never take the amount of data in each data event chunk for granted, unless the documentation of the specific API explicitly specify how the data event is emitted.